# Could someone please explain to me about Directional Filter Bank?

Tags: image-processing, filter-bank

I'm learning about Directional Filter Banks for my Thesis about Image Enhancement. I read it from some papers (Bamberger(1992) and Park(2004)) but I still cannot understand it clearly in detail. Could anyone here please explain it to me the process? Does it applied on Frequency domain or Spatial domain?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have links to those papers? Or are they not available without a subscription?

Comment: @Phonon : Thank you for your response. I found the paper on IEEE. This is from Park (2004)[link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1344034&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1344034).
that paper is considered as the Default DFB, as far as I know.

And this is from Bamberger(1992)[link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=127960&contentType=Journals+%26+Magazines&refinements%3D4281749888%26ranges%3D1992_1992_p_Publication_Year%26queryText%3Dbamberger). 
That paper is the initial publication of DFB.

Comment: [Crossposted on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10515/98).

Comment: @Raphael I'm so sorry. I've deleted the other one on Computer Science. Thank you.